# Python Hazmat Cryptography customize input to HKDF from output of ECDH

Tags: python, cryptography, ecdh

The counterpart to my ECDH key exchange uses a non-standard form for the input key material to an HKDF function. Not simply the calculated EC point, or EC x-coordinate as is often the case. Rather they use an amalgamation of the Curve point and calculated point coordinates. Using Python I am trying to mock up what they will be doing so I can test my decryption code.

The problem I am having is with 'customizing' the input to the HKDF function in Python. I do not know what is the output of the `exchange()` function (variable `shared_key`). Using `type()` tells me "bytes-like object" and the Hazmat Crytography documentation does not elaborate on what this output value represents. I thought it is the calculated point on the EC but it does not start with the 0x04 or 0x03 byte indicating an EC point.

Here's my python function which is doing the ECDH operation:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ec
    def eciesEncrypt(publicKey, plaintext, aad):
        epk = ec.generate_private_key(ec.SECP256R1())
        shared_key = epk.exchange(ec.ECDH(), publicKey)
        iv = os.urandom(12)
        
        derived_key = HKDF(
            algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
            length=32,
            salt=None,
            info=None,
        ).derive(shared_key)
    
        cipherText = aesgcm256_encrypt_buffer(derived_key, iv, aad, plaintext)
        
        return iv, cipherText
```

Basically, I want to understand what is the value of `shared_key` representing so that I can form the proper input to HKDF for my use case. Thank you.

Comment: `shared_key`  is the _shared secret_, i.e. the x coordinate (bytes-like object) of the EC point that results from the multiplication of the private key (`epk`) and public key (`publicKey`). Why do you think that `exchange()` does something different? Maybe I misunderstand the question.

Comment: Thank you! That is precisely what I needed to know. I wasn't sure, because some other library functions (for example mbedtls in C code) return the whole calculated point.